# Using Stack Exchange to look for scholarly articles and working with the scientific community

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I have been part of a university for a few years now. I have learnt on my own and from my colleagues how to look for scientific papers and how the community works.

I realized I could not find any resource that would be able to answer my questions regarding universities, scholarly articles and knowledge as a whole.

There are Stack Exchange sites regarding specific topics such as programming, maths, etc.

What should I use when I want to get to know how to publish, find and work with scientific papers?

Where do I look for papers (or even look for a way to look for it) that I can't find on scholarly search engines?

It happens a lot in cases where I don't fully understand the topic or lack the proper vocabulary I am searching. Sometimes in a community some papers are well known but to a newbie they are impossible to find.

Comment: Did you check Academia: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ?

Comment: There are also two educator sites [CS](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Math](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which might on a tangent be interested in finding and work with scientific papers. Before asking there consult their meta first as I doubt it fits 100% there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your questions are related to the topics of [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> This site is for **academics** of all levels – from students to senior researchers – as well as anyone in or interested in research-related or research-adjacent fields. New users (even users familiar with the Stack Exchange format) are invited to read our [introduction to the site](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/1203) before posting.
>
> If you have a question about ...
>
> - academic careers,
> - requirements and expectations of students, postdocs, or professors,
> - inner workings of research departments,
> - academic writing and publishing,
> - studying and teaching at institutions of higher education (universities, colleges, …),
> - the academic research process,
>
> ... then you're in the right place!

So I would read that introduction and then decide how to pose your question.

Comment: This answers most of my question. I misunderstood the purpose of Academia at first glance. 

What remains of my question is how do i directly ask people to help me look for specific papers? Example: I would want to find papers about the harmfullness of using detergents in wild reservoirs. From what I understand on Academia I can ask about how to look for it but not about the answers themselves?

Comment: Some communities allow [resource-request] types of questions, but I'm struggling to find a SE site where you can ask questions about wildlife reservoirs ...

Comment: @Prusio Maybe on some sites there is at least some chance that you might get response to such request in chat. OTOH, many sites have rather low activity in their chatroom - in connection with your example I thought about [Biology](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=biology.stackexchange.com) and [Medicial Sciences](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=medicalsciences.stackexchange.com) - in both cases, the main chatroom seems to be rather silent.

Comment: @Martin: Perhaps it'd be considered within the scope of  one or both of the main sites. In general it's a good idea to check on a site's Meta to see what approach they recommend for reference requests. For example https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6308/17230.